# docker bind-mounting a managed volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

what does docker do, when you bind-mount a volume in your docker "run" command, 
which is already a managed volume defined in the docker build file/ image?

Example:

- dockerfile defines /myvolume as managed volume
- then: docker run -v /< my_host_dir >:/myvolume ... /< image >

What I see is that the managed volume is no longer created.
Instead the bind-mount comes through and mounts the host-dir into the container.

What goes on behind the scenes?
Is this documented somewhere and therefor something one can count on?

br volker

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "What I see is that the managed volume is no longer created". `/myvolume` should exist inside the container weather or not you have bind-mounted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VOLUME` statement in a *Dockerfile* just marks the directory as to be mounted from somewhere else to help users of the image. For example when you create a Database-Image, the user of that image usually wants to persist the date outside of the container.

If you (as the creator of the Image/writer of the Dockerfile) marked a directory as a `VOLUME`, the user of the image (the one who executes `docker run` or similar) has an idea, where in the container he should mount a directory from outside.

Comment: Thanks Martin, just checking back: when the user of the image does not care where Docker stores the volume, he just uses the image as it is. He can always find out with "docker inspect". But if he wants the files in certain location on the host, he specifies a bind-mount in the "docker run" command. That so?

Comment: No. Just having a `VOLUME` statement in a Dockerfile doesn't influence the host at all. It's just a label. When the user doesn't provide a `-v` flag on start, no directory will be created on the host. (`-v` mounts an exisiting directory OR creates the directory and than mounts it)